# How to deal with checksum issue in maven 2.2.1

Tags: maven-2, dspace

everything was working super fine until for no reason, maven start giving me some checksum warning and then compilation error

I have cleaned my repository several time now but i still get the same error:

[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] snapshot org.dspace:dspace-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from maven.dspace.org-snapshot
[WARNING] * CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '3fa219291cb220dea33cb85c84cefb6c14eb16d9'; remote = ' CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '3fa219291cb220dea33cb85c84cefb6c14eb16d9'; remote = '

Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.dspace:dspace-api:jar': Error getting POM for 'org.dspace:dspace-api' from the repository: Unable to read local copy of metadata: Cannot read metadata from '/Users/maatary/.m2/repository/org/dspace/dspace-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-maven.dspace.org-snapshot.xml': entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...://searchassist.verizon.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=... @1:245) 
  org.dspace:dspace-api:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

for project org.dspace:dspace-api
  org.dspace:dspace-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

I don't recall making any update on my osx recently, e.g. such as a java version update. The only thing that may have change is my version of Intellij. I'm running there latest release now. I don't recall if after i did the update i successfully ran a build. Either way i have the same problem on the command line.

I just don't understand why it would happens just suddenly.

I can't use maven 3.0 for some specific reason unfortunately.

If anyone has any useful insight that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Edit

*here is what is in the bad file (i.e. maven-metadata-maven.dspace.org-snapshot.xml)*:

> http://searchassist.verizon.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=us&ParticipantID=euekiz39ksg8nwp7iqj2fp5wzfwi5q76&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fmaven.dspace.org%2Fsnapshot%2Forg%2Fdspace%2Fdspace-api%2F0.0.1-SNAPSHOT%2Fmaven-metadata.xml&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0&method=GET"/>url="http://searchassist.verizon.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=us&ParticipantID=euekiz39ksg8nwp7iqj2fp5wzfwi5q76&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fmaven.dspace.org%2Fsnapshot%2Forg%2Fdspace%2Fdspace-api%2F0.0.1-SNAPSHOT%2Fmaven-metadata.xml&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0&method=GET";if(top.location!=location){var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+="&w="+x+"&h="+y;}window.location.replace(url);

Comment: What version of DSpace are you trying to build?  It seems to be trying to download version "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" which is not a valid version of DSpace.

Please note that DSpace 4.x and above REQUIRE Maven 3.x or above (see their installation docs). So, if you are trying to build DSpace 4 or 5, it's not going to work with Maven 2.2.x

Comment: Also, based on what is in the "bad file", it looks like Verizon "Search Assist" (http://searchassist.verizon.com) is intercepting your download.

Comment: From the OP's past questions, they're using a highly customised 1.8.x. DSpace 1.8.x should still build with Maven 2 IIRC. But as you say @TimDonohue, it looks like the problem isn't actually with maven, it's somewhere in the download. MaatDeamon, what happens if you delete / rename your maven directory (/Users/maatary/.m2/repository) and try again?